# ssh-keyscan not found in Dockerfile

Tags: docker

I have a simple Dockerfile, exactly as below:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y upgrade

RUN mkdir -p /root/.ssh
RUN touch /root/.ssh/known_hosts

RUN ssh-keyscan github.com >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts
```

The result of running:

```
docker build -no-cache -t testimage .
```

is:

```
Step 5 : RUN ssh-keyscan github.com >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts
 ---> Running in e11ef5962a11
/bin/sh: 1: ssh-keyscan: not found
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You would need to install ssh first.

```
RUN  apt-get -yq update && \
     apt-get -yqq install ssh
```

Then, the various ssh commands, including `ssh-keyscan`, would be available.

That is what I did in my [`sshd` image Dockerfile](https://github.com/VonC/b2d/blob/679c9453058c7d8fcf1cf2ee4dc40e7a7746c17a/sshd/Dockerfile#L9).
I used it to [add `localhost` to my `.ssh/known_hosts`](https://github.com/VonC/b2d/blob/679c9453058c7d8fcf1cf2ee4dc40e7a7746c17a/sshd/post_install_ssh.sh#L38-L46) in order to make some test locally on the `sshd` server.

As [commented below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32665746/ssh-keyscan-not-found-in-dockerfile#comment60352354_32665960) by [pjotr-dolphin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/788022/pjotr-dolphin):

> If you are only after `ssh-keyscan`, [`openssh-client`](https://wiki.debian.org/SSH#Installation_of_the_client) has smaller footprint than ssh package.

Actually, [package `openssh-clients` for RedHat/CentOS](https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=openssh-clients), as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32665746/ssh-keyscan-not-found-in-dockerfile/32665960?noredirect=1#comment91061497_32665960) by [Oleg Neumyvakin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1592008/oleg-neumyvakin)

Comment: Great! It didn't occur to me that ssh wasn't already installed. But given that ssh into docker seems to be an anti-practice, I suppose that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @KevinArrrrrg yes, for just accessing a running container from the docker engine host, a `docker exec <container> bash` is enough. But for accessing a running container from another machine, ssh is a legitimate listener, whic has to be installed though.

Comment: If you are only after ssh-keyscan, openssh-client has smaller footprint than ssh package.

Comment: @pjotr_dolphin Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: On RedHat/Centos based systems:  `openssh-clients`