# Git Clone using SSH in Dockerfile

Tags: git, docker, ssh, dockerfile

I am trying to clone a git repository using ssh in a docker image and i want to do this while building the dockerfile. I can make this work using git clone https with username and password, but using ssh, it fails. My dockerfile looks like

```
# Install software 
RUN apt-get install -y git
# Make ssh dir
RUN mkdir -p /${APP_USER}/.ssh/

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -qq -y install curl
RUN apt-get -qq -y install \
  openssh-client openssh-server
ADD id_rsa /${APP_USER}/.ssh/id_rsa

# Create known_hosts
RUN touch /${APP_USER}/.ssh/known_hosts
# Add bitbuckets key
RUN ssh-keyscan bitbucket.org >> /${APP_USER}/.ssh/known_hosts

# Pull the master branch 
RUN cd ${HOME} \
 && git clone ssh://git@bitbucket.services...... \
 && ls -la
```

I have added steps to install git, copied the private ssh key to the user folder, placed the public key in bitbucket repo, added known hosts but still i get the following error

```
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: You do `ssh-keyscan bitbucket.org` but `git clone ssh://git@bitbucket.services`. Shouldn't these be the same host? Either `ssh-keyscan bitbucket.services` or `git clone ssh://git@bitbucket.org`?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, i corrected that but that results in the following

`ssh-keyscan bitbucket.services
write (bitbucket.services): Connection refused`

Comment: "connection refused" means there's nobody listening on port 22 on whatever IP address `bitbucket.services` resolves to. (Note that running `git clone` *in* a docker instance is generally unwise in the first place, since it requires putting credentials into the docker image, where they may leak.)

Answer (score 3):

Add a RUN `ssh -Tv git@bitbucket.services` to check for any error message.

I would suspect for instance a chmod issue

```
RUN \
    chmod 700 $HOME/.ssh &&\
    chmod 600 $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa
```

As commented, `ssh-keyscan` (if you [have installed it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32665960/6309)) can be needed, to complete the `ssh/known_hosts` file. For instance:

```
# Authorize SSH Host
RUN mkdir -p /root/.ssh && \
    chmod 0700 /root/.ssh && \
    ssh-keyscan example.com > /root/.ssh/known_hosts && \
    # Add the keys and set permissions
    echo "$PRIVATE_SSH_KEY" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa && \
    chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, i tried the above steps. This is what i get from ssh -Tv command

`OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.4, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.services [] port 22.
debug1: connect to address  port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host bitbucket.services port 22: Connection refused`

Comment: I do have another issue as pointed out by @phd my ssh-keyscan had a different address

Now when i do ssh-keyscan i get 

`write (bitbucket.services): Connection refused`

Comment: @UsmanZahid `/${APP_USER}/.ssh` is not the standard path used by `ssh`: `ssh` will use `${HOME}/.ssh`, which, if you are running those commands as `root`, will be `/root/.ssh`. Check first who you are when running those commands in Dockerfile (`RUN id -a`)