# GitHub Actions to SSH into a linux machine created by terraform and run remote commands on it

Tags: linux, ssh, terraform, github-actions

I am creating a Azure Linux VM using terraform through GitHub Actions. Once the VM gets created, I am using the outputs.tf file to get the Keys, FQDN, IP Address and user name, storing it in environment variables. Then i am trying to use these variables to SSH into the server in order to run remote commands on it. Here is my code

```
name: 'Terraform'

on:
  push:
    branches:
    - "development"
    paths:
     - 'Infrastructure/**'
  pull_request:

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  terraform:
    name: 'Terraform'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        shell: bash        
    env:
      ARM_CLIENT_ID: ${{ secrets.ARM_CLIENT_ID }}
      ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: ${{ secrets.ARM_CLIENT_SECRET }}
      ARM_TENANT_ID: ${{ secrets.ARM_TENANT_ID }}
      ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: ${{ secrets.ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}
      ARM_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.ARM_ACCESS_KEY }}
      
    steps:        
    # Checkout the repository to the GitHub Actions runner
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
      with:
        repository: 'myrepo/ModernDelivery'       
        ref: 'development'
        
    # Initialize a new or existing Terraform working directory by creating initial files, loading any remote state, downloading modules, etc.
    - name: Terraform Create Infrastructure
      working-directory: ./Infrastructure
      run: |
        terraform init
        terraform validate        
        terraform plan -out "infra.tfplan"
        terraform apply "infra.tfplan"
        echo "SSH_USER=$(terraform output -raw linuxsrvusername | sed 's/\s*=\s*/=/g' | xargs)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
        echo "SSH_KEY=$(terraform output -raw tls_public_key | sed 's/\s*=\s*/=/g' | xargs)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
        echo "SSH_HOST=$(terraform output -raw linuxsrvpublicip | sed 's/\s*=\s*/=/g' | xargs)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
        echo "SSH_FQDN=$(terraform output -raw linuxsrvfqdn | sed 's/\s*=\s*/=/g' | xargs)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
        echo $SSH_USER
        echo $SSH_KEY
        echo $SSH_HOST
        echo $SSH_FQDN
        
    - name: Configure SSH and login
      shell: bash
      env:
        SSH_USER: ${{ env.SSH_USER }}
        SSH_KEY: ${{ env.SSH_KEY }}
        SSH_HOST: ${{ env.SSH_HOST }}
        SSH_FQDN: ${{ env.SSH_FQDN }}
      run: |
        sudo -i
        cd /home/runner
        sudo hostname $SSH_HOST
        mkdir -p /home/runner/ssh
        mv ssh .ssh
        echo "$SSH_KEY" > /home/runner/.ssh/authorized_keys
        chmod 0600 /home/runner/.ssh/authorized_keys
        cat >>/home/runner/.ssh/config <<END
        Host chefssh
          HostName $SSH_HOST
          User $SSH_USER
          IdentityFile /home/runner/.ssh/authorized_keys
          PubKeyAuthentication yes
          StrictHostKeyChecking no
        END
        ssh chefssh -t sudo -- "sh -c 'sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y'"
```

I am getting the below error when Github actions run

```
Run sudo -i
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Warning: Permanently added '111.222.333.444' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Load key "/home/runner/.ssh/authorized_keys": invalid format
pha_xDuW3lc@111.222.333.444: Permission denied (publickey).
Error: Process completed with exit code 255.
```

This seems to tell me that the key passed in Authorized Keys is not valid. Which brings me to the question, which key is required. With terraform i have 4 keys which can be generated

1. private_key_openssh - this is a Private Key data in OpenSSH PEM format
2. private_key_pem - This is Private Key data in PEM(RFC 1421) format
3. public_key_openssh - The public key data in "Authorized Keys" format.
4. public_key_pem - This is Public Key data in PEM(RFC 1421) format

which among the 4 needs to be in authorized_keys. Also are any other keys need to be added under .ssh folder?

Answer (score 0):

A `ssh testhost -tt` would use the /home/current-user/.ssh/config file, which differs from `sudo cat >>~/.ssh/config`.

If your `sudo` commands are done with the user `root`, the config file modifed would be `/home/root/.ssh/config`.
That would explain your error message, where the right `config` file is not found, and the entry `Host testhost` is not found.

Instead of using `~`, try and use the full path, or at least `echo $HOME` to make sure you are using the expected path.

Comment: `~` is expanded by the shell to the current user’s home directory. It being used as an argument to `sudo` or the target of a redirection of the output of `sudo` won’t change whose home directory it expands to.

Comment: @Biffen I agree. I just prefer to be explicit in this case.

Comment: I debugged this further and noticed that mkdir command did not work. i listed echo $HOME which gave me /home/runner. I then listed $PWD which gave me /home/runner/work/TSOModernDelivery/TSOModernDelivery. I then gave the command mkdir -p /home/runner/work/TSOModernDelivery/TSOModernDelivery/.ssh/, but .ssh folder was not created. I tried cd /home/runner and it gives me cd command not found. (so mkdir and cd commands are not working)

Comment: @RAnand A `.ssh` folder should be in `/home/runner`, not in a subfolder. And with the [right permissions - `chmod`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71615271/6309)

Comment: @VonC i navigated to /home/runner directory and did a dir and it gives factory  perflog  runners  warmup  work. there is no .ssh folder. Also i changed the /home/runner directory permissions to 777 and then did a dir. same result. no .ssh folder

Comment: @RAnand Note that chmod 777 would make any `.ssh` subfolder inoperable. Any parent folder of a .ssh with write access for "all" would trigger a "Permissions are too open" error message.

Comment: @VonC - kindly see the edited post. I was able to move ahead but getting stuck with keys . Any idea which key needs to go where?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248487/discussion-between-vonc-and-ranand).